# fancyBox2: Slideshow Buttons and Image Border

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is it possible to only have the slideshow on/off button and position 
that somewhere inside the title area ?  My reason for wanting this is 
because the button bar reduces the size of the image shown and I only want to have the option 
to turn the Slideshow On or Off, Navigation is done by the normal left and right
clicking of the image.

Is it possible to reduce the border around the image, especially the bottom border ?  I tried settings for padding and margin, but got some unexpected results. is there an example
anywhere of the exact syntax ?

Thanks

mcl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to create your own play/pause buttons. In my case I created them out of the fancybox buttons (helpers/fancybox_buttons.png) with this css:

```
a.myPlay {
 /* set the proper path to the png file */
 background-image:  url("fancybox2.0.4/helpers/fancybox_buttons.png");
 background-color: #2a2a2a;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: block;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 float: left; 
 margin-right: 20px;
}
a.myPlay {
 background-position: 0 -30px;
}
a.myPlayON {
 background-position: -30px -30px;
}
```

and some extra (inline css) style applied to the `fancybox-title` class to tweak my `title` (optional):

```
.fancybox-title {
 min-height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
}
```

Then the script that does the trick (`helpers` and `afterLoad` are the important options to set) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  nextEffect : 'fade',
  prevEffect : 'fade',
  openEffect : 'fade',
  closeEffect : 'fade',
  closeBtn : 'true',
  arrows : 'true',
  helpers : { 
   title : { type : 'inside' }
  },
  afterLoad: function(){
   if($.fancybox.player.isActive){ 
    this.title = '<a href="javascript:$.fancybox.play();" title="Slideshow" class="myPlay myPlayON" onclick="$(\'.myPlay\').toggleClass(\'myPlayON\')">pause</a> Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
   } else {
    this.title = '<a href="javascript:$.fancybox.play();" title="Slideshow" class="myPlay" onclick="$(\'.myPlay\').toggleClass(\'myPlayON\')">play</a> Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
   } // if else
  } // afterLoad
 }); //fancybox
}); // ready
```

Just bear in mind that **you still need to load the fancybox's buttons js and css files** regardless that you are not using the `helpers` > `buttons` option.

A working [DEMO HERE](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/playButtoninTitle_10mar12.html). Use at your own risk ;)

Comment: That is just what I wanted.  Many, many thanks.  I will report back when I get it installed.