# Fancybox title - change depending on slideshow state

Tags: jquery, fancybox

In the title, I'm trying to get a pause and play button (separate button) along with the word "Paused" when the slideshow is stopped. `autoPlay` is set to true for now.

I found this: [fancyBox2: Slideshow Buttons and Image Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646143/fancybox2-slideshow-buttons-and-image-border) and it seems to have gotten me close to an answer but I'm still having problems. When I click on Pause/Play, the text will be shown when the next slide in the slideshow is displayed (so it doesn't update the current slide). The code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".launcher").click(function() {
        $.fancybox.open({
        helpers: {
            title:{
                type: 'inside'
            }
        },
        loop: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        playSpeed: 5000,
        nextSpeed: 1500,
        prevSpeed: 1500,
        prevEffect: 'fade',
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        afterLoad: function() {
            if ($.fancybox.player.isActive){
                this.title = '<a href="javascript:$.fancybox.play();"><img src="/assets/images/simple-pause.png"></a> <a href="javascript:$.fancybox.play();"><img src="/assets/images/simple-play.png"></a>';
            } else {
                this.title = '<a href="javascript:$.fancybox.play();"><img src="/assets/images/simple-pause.png"></a> <a href="javascript:$.fancybox.play();"><img src="/assets/images/simple-play.png"></a> <span class="pausetext"><h3>Paused</h3></span>';
            }
        }
    });
        return false;
});
});
```

I've tried variations on what I have there; adding an onclick to toggle the span, span in both titles with and without the onclick. Nothing I've done will immediately hide/show the span though. Also, when the lightbox first opens, it always shows the title within the `else` portion (so it says "Paused" even though it's autoplaying). As soon as it goes to the next slide, though, it goes to the correct title. What am I missing here?

Comment: in my example (that I said "use at your own risk") the `autoPlay` is set to `false` so you have to invert the `if` action by the `else`. Also in my demo, I use classes with different styles to toggle the button.... but again, "use it at your own risk" (this demo is a customized solution that is totally unsupported ....unless you want to hire somebody for your own customization ;)

Comment: I've hired myself! Seriously though, I basically copied your example (and inverted the `if` and `else` actions. There seems to be an issue when `autoPlay` is set to `true` and trying to determine whether the fancybox is active or not. Seems that for the first slide when the box opens, the `isActive` is always false.

Comment: maybe if you upgrade to v2.1.3 and use `beforeShow` instead of `afterLoad`

Comment: Nope. Already using 2.1.3. `beforeShow` has the same behavior as `afterLoad`. Also tried `afterShow` and `beforeLoad` just for the heck of it, but no go.