# set autoplay to false/true on fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have an image gallery.

```
jQuery("a.thumb").fancybox({
  "loop"        : true,
  "autoPlay"    : true,
  "playSpeed"   : 4000,
  "nextSpeed"   : 500,
  "prevSpeed"   : 500,
  "openSpeed"   : 500,
  "speedOut"    : 500,
  "openEffect"  : "fade", 
  "closeEffect" : "fade",
  "nextEffect"  : "fade",
  "prevEffect"  : "fade"
});
```

I want to add a new button to set the autoplay to false/true is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9649457/1055987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsFiddle DEMO Title Bar with Autoplay Show Button**](http://jsfiddle.net/GjNnj/1/) *(Alternate images for visual confirmation)*

[**jsFiddle DEMO Title Overlay with Autoplay Show Button**](http://jsfiddle.net/GjNnj/3/)

You can place a button inside the Fancybox Title area that when clicked will stop or play the Fancybox show. It will also do a image swap to visually indicate the current playback mode.

***The jsFiddle DEMO above contains complete tutorial comments.***

**CSS:**

```css
.fancyControl {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var fancyControlMode = "play";

function fancyPlay(){
  $.fancybox.play();
  $('.fancybox-title .child img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/40x24/00ff00/000000&text=PLAY');
  fancyControlMode = "play";
}

function fancyStop(){
  $.fancybox.play();
  $('.fancybox-title .child img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/40x24/ff0000/000000&text=STOP');
  fancyControlMode = "stop";
}

function fancyButton() {
  if (fancyControlMode === "play") {
    $('.fancybox-title .child').prepend('<img class="fancyControl" src="http://placehold.it/40x24/00ff00/000000&text=PLAY" />');
    $('.fancyControl').toggle(fancyStop, fancyPlay);
  } else {
    $('.fancybox-title .child').prepend('<img class="fancyControl" src="http://placehold.it/40x24/ff0000/000000&text=STOP" />');
    $('.fancyControl').toggle(fancyPlay, fancyStop);
  }
}

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  autoPlay: true,
  afterShow: fancyButton
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this:

Assume that there is check box which id="chkFlag" in your html.

```
var flag="";
$('#chkFlag').live("change", function() {
       if ($('#chkShowImage').attr("checked"))
             flag = true;
        else
             flag = false ;

      });
```

and in your function use flag:

```
 jQuery("a.thumb").fancybox({        
            'loop'              : true,
            'autoPlay'          : flag,
            'playSpeed'         : 4000,
            'nextSpeed'         : 500,
            'prevSpeed'         : 500,
            'openSpeed'         : 500,
            'speedOut'          : 500,
            'openEffect'        : 'fade', 
            'closeEffect'       : 'fade',
            'nextEffect'        : 'fade',
            'prevEffect'        : 'fade'
             });
```

Comment: Try to avoid using `live()` as it has been deprecated. [`on()` is the future!](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

@arttonics, I'm blown away by your fancyBox mastery. Here's another way:

Unlike the question @JFK linked, @Xone you don't say you need the button to be within the title area, or even the lightbox frame. You might be satisfied with the "buttons" helper packaged with fancyBox. It supplies a button bar with 'prev', 'play/pause', 'next', 'full-size'/'fit', and 'close' buttons. Just add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your-path-to/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
```

(right before `</body>`) and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your-path-to/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css"/>
```

(in `<head>`; the placeholder paths I've used reflect where the files are found when you download fancyBox).

Your basic fancyBox gallery with autoplay and control buttons will be

```
$(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
    autoPlay    : true,
    closeBtn    : false, // remove the default close button (there's one in the button bar)
    arrows      : false, // (optional) remove the default prev/next hover arrows (they duplicate the button bar's arrows)
    helpers     : {
        buttons : {} // add the buttons bar
    }
});
```

Customizing those buttons should be straight forward if you're alright with CSS - thanks to @fancyapps for making jquery.fancybox-buttons.css readable! I can imagine you might also end up going into jquery.fancybox-buttons.js to tweak the `<div id="fancybox-buttons">` it injects.