# Slideshow controls for Fancybox 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox 2 to display slideshows of image galleries on various pages of my website. I have had complaints that users don't know how to stop the slideshow and navigate through the slideshow at their own pace.

Is there any way to display a small stop/start icon beneath the caption - or even add a small "Use spacebar to stop/start slideshow" comment in very small type beneath the photo caption?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646143/fancybox2-slideshow-buttons-and-image-border). 
The first answer might help you.

Or, just a thought, maybe you can edit the templates of fancybox, to add your custom control, and events.

If you prefer to try the seconde option, look at the [docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) and search for "tpl"

Hope it's gonna help you.